# Heap dump in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I was able to do a heap dump of the path and I don't remember how I did it. The output looks like this:

```
{
  "Data Address" = 0x0000000001120bf0,
  "Header Address" = 0x0000000001120be0
  "Block Size" = 800
  "Heap Handle" = 0x0000000001110000
  "Segment Index" = 0
  "New" =
  "Data Preview" = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\iCLS\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\iCLS\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6\\;C:\\Users\\brazg\\.cargo\\bin;C:\\Users\\brazg\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\bin;C:\\Users\\brazg\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin"
}
```

Is there a way to reproduce this?
I think I used something like `Format-Custom -InputObject (Some-Thing)`

Comment: I have the output because I used Out-File. Just no good record of how I did it. Just some ideas.

Comment: Have you tried Get-History

Comment: Yes I did but, the command I found doesn't give the same output for some reason. I'm quite confused.

Comment: Whats the command you found?

Comment: `Format-Custom  -InputObject (Get-ChildItem Env:\Path) | Out-File`

Comment: Your output looks like something from NirSoft's [**HeapMemView** utility](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/heap_memory_view.html)

Comment: it does. the question is, how did I do it? Cause the command doesn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you exported the HeapMemView report as HTML, you can reformat the HTML report using PowerShell to resemble your output with something like so:

```
$html = Get-Content -Path .\report.html -Raw

$file = New-Object -Com 'HtmlFile'
$file.IHTMLDocument2_write($html)
$table = $file.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('TABLE')
$cells = $table | Select-Object -ExpandProperty cells
$rowCount = ($table | Select-Object -ExpandProperty rows).length
$colCount = $cells.length / $rowCount

[PSObject[]]$result = $null
for($i = 1; $i -lt $rowCount; $i++) {
    $row = New-Object System.Object
    for($j = 0; $j -lt $colCount; $j++) {
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $cells[$j].innerText.Trim() -Value $cells[($i*$colCount)+$j].innerText.Trim()
    }
    $result += $row
}

Format-Custom -InputObject $result | Out-File .\reformatted.txt
```

If interested, the reformatted output resembles:

```
class Object
{
  Data Address = 0x0000000004524050
  Header Address = 0x0000000004524040
  Block Size = 80
  Heap Handle = 0x0000000004520000
  Segment Index = 0
  New = 
  Data Preview = 
}
```

Although, if JSON format is preferred, then swap-out the last line with:

```
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $result | Out-File .\reformatted.txt
```

The reformatted text file contents resemble:

```
{
    "Data Address":  "0x0000000004524050",
    "Header Address":  "0x0000000004524040",
    "Block Size":  "80",
    "Heap Handle":  "0x0000000004520000",
    "Segment Index":  "0",
    "New":  "",
    "Data Preview":  ""
}
```

While this may not be exactly what you had originally done in PowerShell, I hope it helps, nonetheless.  Good luck.